# Trouble with trigger using GETDATE

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm completely stumped on this one. I have a trigger that's supposed to send an email if a record has been inserted into the table, but only if hasn't been inserted in the last 20 minutes or so. I've narrowed it down to the fact that it simply does not like GETDATE() in the insert query.

If I update my stored procedure to insert a static date time string like "2013-03-07 09:53:54.12", it will execute the trigger and construct the email body so it can be sent. If it's using GETDATE() or SYSDATETIME() in the stored procedure, the body variable will be empty after it runs the select command.

Am I missing something? I haven't be able to find anything posted prior on this, but I apologize is scenario has already been posted and resolved here.

My insert command in my MVC project looks like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationEntriesConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RegisterCustomerDownload", conn);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userEmail);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FileDownloaded", "Product Name Here");

        try
        {
            //Open connection and try to execute the command
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO TrialDownloads(Email, FileDownloaded, DownloadTime) 
VALUES(@Email, @FileDownloaded, GETDATE());
```

From there, I have a trigger (for insert) than sends an email if the last matching record was inserted longer than 20 minutes ago:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

--For debugging purposes
INSERT INTO [DebugLog] (message) VALUES ('Entered SendTrialDownloadEmail');

SELECT @body += 'A trial has been downloaded:' +
        CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)+ 'Email Address: ' + Email +
        CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)+ 'Product Downloaded ' + FileDownloaded +
        CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)+ 'Date Downloaded: ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DownloadTime)
    FROM [inserted] i 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TrialDownloads] o 
        WHERE 20 > DATEDIFF(minute, o.DownloadTime, GETDATE()) 
            AND i.Email = o.Email 
            AND i.FileDownloaded = o.FileDownloaded);

--For debugging purposes
INSERT INTO [DebugLog] (message) VALUES ('Before IF block');
INSERT INTO [DebugLog] (message) VALUES (@body);
DECLARE @insertCount NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @insertCount = CONVERT(nvarchar, COUNT(*)) FROM inserted
INSERT INTO DebugLog (message) VALUES (@insertCount);


IF NOT @body = N''
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name="NoReplyProfile",
            @recipients="email@domain.com",
            @subject="A Trial has been downloaded",
            @body=@body;
        INSERT INTO [DebugLog] (message) VALUES ('Mail sent');
        INSERT INTO [DebugLog] (message) VALUES (@body);
    END
```

Comment: First, never send an email in a trigger. You shoudl send teh records to be sent emails to a pable and then run a job every 5 minutes or so to send the emails. You do not want to break inserts if teh email server goes down.

Comment: @HLGEM Isn't that exactly how sp_send_dbmail behaves in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: What data type is DownloadTime column?

Comment: I was under the impression that sp_send_dbmail did this already. Does it not? Also, DateTime2 is the data type of DownloadTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what Jason noticed, I would say the best thing to do would be to also filter your NOT EXIST (...) clause on a key field or the `TrialRegistrations` table. I think you should be straight if you do that.

...

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TrialDownloads] o 
        WHERE 20 > DATEDIFF(minute, o.DownloadTime, GETDATE()) 
            AND i.Email = o.Email 
            AND i.FileDownloaded = o.FileDownloaded
            AND NOT i.Id = o.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the main thing is that you're basing your email on a WHERE NOT EXISTS a row in your main table where the date difference between that row and right now is LESS THAN than 20 minutes and that row shares the same email and filedownloaded values as an inserted value.

So you're only going to get an email if there is NOT a row where that's true, but you already have a row where it is true, the row you just inserted.

Comment: I think that's right. 20 > DATEDIFF(minute, o.DownloadTime, GETDATE()) reads to me like the difference is less than 20 minutes; so he's saying that he doesn't want to send mail for entries that have a match less than 20 minutes old.

Comment: @MojoFilter Which would be OK, if it wasn't for the row that he just inserted. I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure the row is considered to be in the main table for this purpose. 

He could instead do an EXISTS check for a datediff greater than 20 so he would only send emails if that were true.

Comment: Oooh, yeah. I thought this was an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger. That would be a problem, I think. The impression I get, though, is that he's using this to throttle the emails that get sent. So checking to see if there is an old one isn't quite enough.

Comment: This was very helpful. You're probably right in that the inserted record is most likely considered part of the table I was querying. I was not aware of this.